# Django-Import-Export: Will not autoincrement table id, during import

Tags: django, postgresql

Running on Django-1.6, django-import-export-0.1.5 and postgresql.x86_64-9.2.5-1:

I have successfully imported data from a csv file.

When I try to add more data manually, I receive the error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Logging in psql:

```
select max(id) from mytable;
  75

SELECT nextval('mytable_id_seq');
  2
```

Apparently, I have to manually adjust the next value of the sequence.

Is this the normal behavior or am I missing some setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for this to work properly, the csv file that will be uploaded, under the `id` header should not contain any values.

This way, Django ORM will auto-increment the values as it finds suitable.

Comment: big problem is that it doesn't let you leave the id field empty in postgresql wia django import export

Comment: @DrayenDörff I am not currently using this plugin, unfortunately I cannot help promptly.